# Can someone explain how this "adding an element to a set" method works?

Tags: ruby, hash

I am new to Ruby and working on some coding exercises. This was the given prompt:

Ruby provides a class named Set in its Standard Library. Let’s make a set of methods that will manipulate a Hash as if it were a Set. Like so:

Note these should be safe methods (no !)

```
set_add_el({}, :x) # => {:x => true}

set_add_el({:x => true}, :x) # => {:x => true} # This should automatically work if the first method worked

set_remove_el({:x => true}, :x) # => {}
```

and so on... there are a few other methods I need to implement. But I'm just trying to get started and maybe i'm not understanding the question fully. What do the comments following the function headings mean? To help me further illustrate my question, I found this solution to the first method online:

```
def set_add_el(set, value)
    if set[value].nil?
        set[value] = true
    end
    return set 
end
```

First, I thought the question was asking to manipulate a hash such that it will act like a mathematical set. I am confused because it appears that the above function takes an array as input. Second, I ran this code and it doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to. I tried passing ([3,4,5], 6) and ([3,4,5], 4) in as arguments. I expected the first to return [3,4,5,6], and the second to just return [3,4,5], since in a set there should be no duplicates. The output for the former returned [3, 4, 5, nil, nil, nil, true] which makes no sense to me.

Comment: It takes a hash, because that's what the exercise is about. [] Is a function on hashes.

Comment: Gah sorry I'm so confused. I thought the syntax for a hash is curly braces, and inside you have to have keys mapping to values. To me it just looked like a plain old array.

Comment: Only hash **literals** are surrounded by curly braces. Here the parameter `set` is, well, a parameter, not a hash literal.

Comment: You might want you take a step back and learn some basic Ruby syntax first-it'll make looking at Ruby code much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You are being asked to show how a hash can be used to mimic a set, where all keys of the hash have the same value `true`. I will address the issue of the hash values later.

The key common properties of sets and hashes is that sets have unique values and hashes have unique keys.

Though the wording you have been given is not very clear, I believe you are being asked to to write two methods,

```
def set_add_el(hash, obj)
  ...
end
```

and

```
def set_remove_el(hash, obj)
  ...
end
```

The first of these is to parallel the method [Set#add](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add). You are to show that your method `set_add_el` method satisfies these two properties:

```
set_add_el({}, :x)              #=> { :x => true }
set_add_el({:x => true}, :x)    #=> { :x => true }
```

The latter method is to parallel the method [Add#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-delete) and must satisfy:

```
set_remove_el({:x => true}, :x) #=> {}
```

While you're at it you may wish to show that your methods have other properties that parallel those of a set, such as the following.

```
set_add_el({:x => true}, :y)    #=> { :x => true, :y => true }
set_remove_el({:x => true}, :y) #=> { :x => true }
```

When convenient, the method [Set#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) can be used to map a `set` into an array of its elements: `set.to_a`. The comparable method for hashes is [Hash#keys](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F): `h.keys` returns an array of the keys of a hash `h` that is used to simulate a set.

While it has been indicated that the hash values are `true` for all keys, they clearly can be any objects. For example, they could all be `nil` or could all be different. If `h` were the hash and `:x` the key to be added, one could even write `h[:x] = ['dog', 'cat', 'pig'].sample`. If `h #=> { :x => 'dog' }`, and `h[:x] = 'cat'`, then `h #=> { :x => 'cat' }`. Hence, while the use of different values changes the hash, it does not change the keys, and as we are only interested in `h.keys`, that's not a problem.